# In JMeter the symbol in Delimiter field is present in csv file

Tags: jmeter

I want to send /api/tour/1/participants?**ParticipantID=-0,001**

ParticipantID=-0,001 and in the "Delimiter" field in "CSV Data Set Config" coma is mentioned.

That's why when I try to send /api/tour/1/participants?**ParticipantID=-0,001** as result /api/tour/1/participants?**ParticipantID=-0** is sending

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any other delimiter.
For example you can use ;or/.Anything other than comma.Then jmeter will pick -0,001 as a single string.

Comment: Thanks. I know about it. But I thought that there is another way

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Change the delimiter both in .csv file and in CSV Data Set Config
2. Surround value having commas with quotation marks like `"0,001"` and change "Allow quoted data?" combobox value to "True"

If you don't have possibility to change the input .csv file - you can still read the data using i.e. [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article for comprehensive information on performing parametrization in JMeter using CSV files.